# Keep setting the external monitor

Tags: resolution, monitor

Every time I turn on my notebook I have to configure the resolution of external monitor with the "grandr." Always turn off the notebook display and change the resolution of external monitor. I wonder if I have some way to configure this setting remain as default every time I turn off the notebook.

Does anyone know how?

I used Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your .xprofile or you can change /etc/X11/xorg.conf.  This is well documented in the wiki at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Four_methods_of_setup and also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_XRandR_changes_persistently